# How to upload remote_url Images using paperclip plugin in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

I am new ROR Developer. i want to upload more than 500000 remote url images using paperclip. i got an error

```
 Error = Too many links - /var/www/railsapp/sample_app/public/system/photos/5815
 Error = Too many links - /var/www/railsapp/sample_app/public/system/photos/48347
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .

 Time Out   :  Error = execution expired

 Error = undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x7f565dc6f218 URL:>
```

can you anybody clarify it? i struggle this position.

Here my rake task for uploading remote url images:

```
   Book.find_in_batches(:conditions=>["image_url is not null and book_id is not null and active=true"],:batch_size=>10000) do |books|
  books.each do |book|
    begin
      book=Book.find_by_id(book.book_id)
      url = URI.parse(book.image_url)
      Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
        if http.head(url.request_uri).code == "200"
          Book.update_attribute(:photo,open(url))
        end
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error => e
     app_logger.debug("Book Photo data load Time Out   :  Error = #{e}")
    rescue Exception => e
     app_logger.debug("Book Photo data load   :  Error = #{e}")
    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've reached the limit of the number of files you can put in a directory, add this to an initialiser in your rails app:

```
# put in /config/initializers/paperclip.rb 

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = 
"/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension" 
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = 
":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, can you help me to figure out the                             error like undefined method `request_uri' for #<URI::Generic:0x7f565dc6f218 URL:>?

Comment: is it possible to create only thumb format file in paperclip without creating original file under rails_root/public/system folder? because of getting Error = No space left on device when uploading more than 5,00,000 images

Comment: Add :styles => { :original => '150x150>'} to your paperclip config (and change the resolution to as small as you need, then it will only store thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Now, it's fine.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Can you guide me how to add sql query in Active scaffold.   Here i have two models books and websites. in book table i have id, name and author. I have price and active fields. Now, i Need to list out only book details active is true.

Comment: Book.find(:all, :conditions => {:active => true})

Comment: yeah completed. i followed these steps to list out only active is true.  i written code in books controller.                                                          def conditions_for_collection
    ['websites.active=true']
  end
  
  def joins_for_collection
      [:websites]
  end

Comment: Hi, Andrew Nebitt. Can you guide me how can I remove delete images under public/system/photo directory which active is false using rake task.